# Is answering a question with an answer that includes multiple questions and possibilities considered an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I am answering a lot of [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) questions and to be completely honest, there are way too many low quality posts with not enough information to answer them. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627429/unable-to-execute-else-statement). This might not actually be that much of a low quality post, but the question itself isn't providing enough information to answer it. So people ask in comments:

- What happens if you do this?
- Did you try?

Some OPs never reply to that. Whenever an OP doesn't reply, I think of actually answering in a similar way as shown below.

**Example answer** (this is not supposed to answer the question I linked):

> Try to `var_dump($variable);` if this returns 0, then there's something wrong with your query and we can't see your database structure, so you have to find the error by yourself. If this returns 1, then you `var_dump($something);` if this doesn't return: `Hello, World`, then there is something wrong with declaring the variable `$something`, which means `$_POST['something']` isn't sending the right information.

This example answer looks very broad, but what if you (as answerer) are 100% sure that one of those 2 (or even 3 or 4) options is the answer? Should this be considered as a legit answer? Or should you just leave this in the comments and never ever get an answer on the question?

Comment: In my opinion, you should dig the question by conversation through comments then you should give a proper answer instead of giving more optional answer.

Comment: Once you tease out the real question, it can be a good idea to get the OP to update the question so that the answer appears pertinent, otherwise it could change again or the comment get deleted.  On some cases, I will quote the key passage at the start of the answer to further make clear what the core problem is.

Comment: @CodeLღver Yeah but in my question, I state that for example the OP wont reply anymore.

Comment: @Plutonix What if there are 4 possible answers and the OP wont specificly tell you the information to find out which answer it should be?

Comment: More than one possible answer is the norm - there is more than one way to do most things.  There should however, be only one question in the post.  If after a comment or two you cant figure out the question perhaps it is too broad or Unclear.

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah ok that is an option yeah. Saying it's too broad but if you're 100% sure it's on of the 2 or perhaps 3 answers you have in mind, would you post an answer or flag it anyway?